# Instagram Chatbot

Tags: python, chatbot, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

There's someone that knows how to reply to Instagram new direct messages automatically?
I've build a python chatbot and I hope to use it to reply to messages but if it's not possible and Azure, AWS, GCP or any other service can be used it's ok. I'm avoiding web scraping.

The aim is to give customers informations about a product and NOT send spam messages to followers.

Searching on the web I understood that instagram API doesn't offer the possibility to reply messages, if I'm wrong and someone can provide me an example or some documentation I'm here!

So the questions are: it's possible to build an instagram bot? If yes, how?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The official public Instagram API does not allow you to access DMs. Therefore, you will not find any documentation for this. However, if you can reverse engineer the private API, you could in theory build an application which runs the same network requests that the Instagram app does. TLDR- yes it is possible.

Comment: There aren't other paid or free services?

Comment: Advertisement isn't allowed on StackOverflow.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, i will search!